FFMPEG 7 : Adding multiple subtitle streams to mkv no longer possible
I recompiled the latest stable version of ffmpeg (7.0) and when I did my usual coding I found an error I don't understand why it's happening. Until ffmpeg 6.1.1 it always worked just fine, but now from version 7.0 it doesn't anymore.
See below for the commandline I used (in msys64) :
/c/Tools/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -xerror -y -i /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American\ Ninja\ 1.mkv -i /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded/
American\ Ninja\ 1.English\ -\ CC.ass -i /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American\ Ninja\ 1.German.ass -i /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded
/American\ Ninja\ 1.Dutch.ass -i /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American\ Ninja\ 1.Italian.ass -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -m
ap 4 -c copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 title=English\ [CC] -disposition:s:s:0 hearing_impaired -
metadata:s:s:1 language=deu -disposition:s:s:1 none -metadata:s:s:2 language=nld -disposition:s:s:2 default -metada
ta:s:s:3 language=ita -disposition:s:s:3 none -attach /f/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American\ Ninja\ 1.png -metadata:s:t:0 f
ilename=small_cover.png -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/png /d/TEMP/American\ Ninja\ 1.mkv

The error ffmpeg gives is :
Stream type specified multiple times
Error parsing options for output file D:/TEMP/American Ninja 1.mkv.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

After some research it has to do about adding the .ass files into the .mkv, and it fails on the -metadata options I gave (not when I only enter the -disposition options). If I only add 1 subtitle-stream, ffmpeg will accept it with any -metadata option(s) I give (for that 1 subtitle stream).
As I said, when I use the previous built of ffmpeg (n6.1.1) it works just fine. But it's not an option for doing the encoding in the latest built, and merging the subtitles using the previous built. I tried that already, but then the previous built complains about pts-pointers not set (possible something has changed in latest built??). I hope someone can help me with this. I don't know how to send an issue at the git-page of ffmpeg as such is not available (normally it is, for other git projects).
Here's the complete output of ffmpeg (with the banner, for compile-options) :
ffmpeg version N-116759-gb40f765962-gcfe0a36352+3 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 14.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --pkg-config=pkgconf --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --ld='ccache g++' --extra-cxxflags=-fpermissive --extra-cflags=-Wno-int-conversion --disable-autodetect --enable-amf --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libaom --disable-debug --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-fontconfig --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libmfx --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libshine --enable-gpl --enable-avisynth --enable-libxvid --enable-libopenmpt --enable-version3 --enable-librav1e --enable-libsrt --enable-libgsm --enable-libvmaf --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-chromaprint --enable-decklink --enable-frei0r --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libilbc --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --enable-librist --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libtesseract --enable-libxavs --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-libcodec2 --enable-ladspa --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libplacebo --enable-libjxl --enable-libvvenc --enable-libvvdec --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-openssl --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCHROMAPRINT_NODLL --extra-cflags=-DZMQ_STATIC --extra-libs=-lpsapi --extra-cflags=-DLIBXML_STATIC --extra-libs=-liconv --disable-w32threads --extra-cflags=-DKVZ_STATIC_LIB --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-DAL_LIBTYPE_STATIC --extra-cflags='-IC:/mabs/local64/include' --extra-cflags='-IC:/mabs/local64/include/AL'
  libavutil      59. 34.100 / 59. 34.100
  libavcodec     61. 11.100 / 61. 11.100
  libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'F:/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American Ninja 1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : American Ninja
    YEAR            : 1985
    MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
    MINOR_VERSION   : 512
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomdby1iso2avc1mp41
    DESCRIPTION     : Joe Armstrong, een eenmansvechtmachine, zit in het leger om uit de gevangenis te blijven en vecht tegen de dodelijk Black Star Order en corrupte criminele leiders om een einde te maken aan illegale wapenhandel.
    SHOW            : American Ninja
    EPISODE_ID      : 1
    ENCODER         : Lavf61.5.101
  Duration: 01:35:50.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6796 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1040 [SAR 1:1 DAR 24:13], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        ENCODER         : Lavc61.11.100 libx264
        DURATION        : 01:35:50.787000000
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        ENCODER         : Lavc61.11.100 ac3
        DURATION        : 01:35:50.859000000
  Stream #0:2(deu): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
      Metadata:
        ENCODER         : Lavc61.11.100 libfdk_aac
        DURATION        : 01:35:50.912000000
Input #1, ass, from 'F:/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American Ninja 1.English - CC.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Subtitle: ass (ssa)
Input #2, ass, from 'F:/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American Ninja 1.German.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #2:0: Subtitle: ass (ssa)
Input #3, ass, from 'F:/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American Ninja 1.Dutch.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #3:0: Subtitle: ass (ssa)
Input #4, ass, from 'F:/Kigo/Film/Recoded/American Ninja 1.Italian.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #4:0: Subtitle: ass (ssa)
Stream type specified multiple times
Error parsing options for output file D:/TEMP/American Ninja 1.mkv.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument


try -disposition:s:0

Tx, that was it. It did always work in previous versions so I couldn't understand why it's no longer accepted in latest version (n7.x). But I gave it a try, and yes, it worked. So thank you for your answer.
